# Brackets Default Theme Location

Tags: adobe-brackets

Brackets comes with two themes installed, "Backets Light (Default)" and "Backets Dark".  To see them, go to View | Themes...

I really like the "Brackets Dark" theme and I'd like to create a duplicate syntax theme of it for GitHub's Atom editor.  I'm trying to locate these two default themes.  Since they aren't third party themes, they aren't in the extensions folder.  My question is where can I locate the "Brackets Dark" theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `main.less` and `package.json` for the Brackets Dark theme here (on Mac):

`/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/www/extensions/default/DarkTheme`

to get to the Contents folder, just right click on the application and hit "Show Package Contents"

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you'll find the files here:

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Brackets\www\extensions\default\DarkTheme`

Comment: And how can I make the dark one to be the default?